# How to delete (null) product attribute in this case special_price

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hi tried multiple ways in Magento 2.1

```
$m2Product->setCustomAttribute('special_price',null)
$m2Product->getCustomAttribute('special_price')->setValue(5);
$m2Product->setData('special_price');
$m2Product->setData('special_price', null);

$m2Product->save();
```

Nothing works

thank's